# Blender texture part disappearing

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have a texture for a hair in file explorer it's normal with the brown part put in blender the brown part becomes transparent? Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first image is not visible. Please [edit] your post

Comment: Can you add more details? The texture alone won't help to guess what the issue is.